# Handling file uploads in Drupal

Tags: drupal, file-upload, large-file-upload

I've been messing around a bit with various solutions to what I would see as a fairly common problem, but I've not yet been able to solve it in a satisfactory way.

What I wish to achieve is some kind of functionality where a user can upload new files, or select existing files to reuse them.

What I've been using so far is a combination of the `filefield`, `filefield_sources`, `imce` and `ckeditor` modules. I guess ckeditor isn't really important for the solution, but I need to be able to embed images from the archive somehow, and this is done with IMCE . Since I do not want everything to be accessible from the filebrowser I created a subdirectory and set full access to it in the IMCE settings, lets call it `default/files/site`

This worked fine as long as all filehanding was done through IMCE, but when I uploaded files directly from the filefield my files ended up in the default/files root, so I set up folders for my fields, for example `default/files/site/movies` in a field that allowed the `.flv` format. This worked fine to, as long as I didn't try to access the files through IMCE. It appears the folders created by filefield are not accessible from IMCE?

I'm also in a position where I need to support large uploads (200MB+), but from my experience in other projects, allowing file uploads through FTP is usually a life-saver, but from what I understand IMCE won't support files not uploaded through Drupal in some way, since they are not present in the database (giving the message: `The selected file could not be used because the file does not exist in the database.`)

I'm aware that I don't really have a clear question to my problem, but somehow I need to figure this out pretty fast. How would I preferably solve this? I'm aware that I'm  not the first to have this problem, but I have not yet been able to find a nice and stable solution. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check this thread (http://drupal.org/node/438940) and the reference to John Locke's work at: http://www.freelock.com/blog/john-locke/2010-02/using-file-field-imported-files-drupal-drush-rescue

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not personally familiar with IMCE off of the top of my head, but if you need files that have been uploaded via ftp to be added to the files tables, then my impulse would be to write a small module which would then allow the user to click a button and start off a batch process.  (This is me assuming that you are using Drupal 6, as the batch api doesn't exist in 5.)

Said batch process would then iterate over all of the files in the appropriate directory, which I would assume you had uploaded the files to, use `file_copy()` (from Drupal's file API) to copy the files to default/files/site, and then would add said files to the files table, which is actually quite simple with `drupal_write_record()`.

It might not even need to use the batch api - it somewhat matters if you're just uploading 10-30 really big files, or 200-300 MB files.

For using the batch api, I'd look at http://drupal.org/node/180528 - this has a fairly basic example of how the batch api works, which basically consists of telling the api that you want to keep calling function_a, and then inside of function_a setting your progress in the context array until you're done, at which time the batch process finishes.  Then you just have whoever uploads the files via ftp to hit a button on the website to move and register the files.

Comment: Looks fairly straight-forward, I'll have a look at it when there is more time since this could be implemented at a later stage, thanks for the advice :)